# Jenkins: how to embed information about the next build in a parameter default

Tags: jenkins

So I need a job parameter to contain the next build number as its default value. This is mostly for information purposes to the user, so could go into the job description instead.

I've taken a look at [dynamic parameters](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in), to little avail.

Obviously, environment variables like BUILD_NUMBER are not set until the job has started building.

This is a stand alone job.

Edit:

The purpose of this parameter is just to provide information to the user who is kicking off the job. The parameter will contain a path to a directory that will be created during the job execution. The name of that dir will contain the build number that created it. /Testing/myTest_job$BUILD_NUMBER

Comment: You need the build number of the next build as parameter for this build. Can you explain what you want to do with this parameter?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a generic description, you can user the [Description Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin).

1. Install the plugin
2. Add Build Step "Set build description" as first Build Step
3. Set "Description" to /Testing/myTest_job${BUILD_NUMBER} and leave "Regular expression" blank

Alternative:

I would suggest to use the post build step "archive artefacts". This will provide the files your job creates as i.e. download link:

http://jenkins.foo.bar/job/example/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/yourfile.exe

Comment: post build? the whole point of the parameter is to let the user know where to go looking at the time they click the build button

Comment: my users tend to click build, then never look at jenkins again until next time

Comment: The file is available when the job is done. The link is always the same. It's the latest successful build.

Comment: Here is what you want!